# Coding strategy to avoid delegate methods

Tags: vb.net, serialization, delegates, json-deserialization

I am coding an application that performs various measurements on 3D objects, using expensive API calls to extract geometric info from another application. These measurements and how they are defined by the user are stored in a `Study` class. This class must be serializable, so that the user can save a particular study with all of it's data to a hard drive, and then load it on another session.

Properties of the 3D object might be `Length`, `Width`, `Height`, `BoundingBoxDimensions`, `Weight`, etc. However, they are not just plain numbers - each property must also store flags if they are requested to be calculated by the user, if they have been evaluated, an error flag, etc.

Some of these properties depend on other properties to be evaluated first (for example, if user requests the value of `BoundingBoxDimensions`, then `Length`, `Width` and `Height` must be calculated first. Therefore, each object property also stores a list of properties it depends on. If it is requested, and it sees that it's dependents are not yet evaluated, then it calls these dependents to be evaluated first.

The goal of this strategy is to minimize the number of API calls and save computation time. For example, if user requests `Length` and `Width` to be evaluated, only 2 API calls would be made (there is no reason to evaluate `Height`). If user calls for `BoundingBoxDimensions`, then 3 API calls have to be made, but no more.

However, this approach also means that I have to use delegate methods to allow different evaluation methods to be assigned to each object property.

This is my code so far.

```
'Main class for a specific 3D object measurement study. It must be serializable.
Public Class Study

    '3D Object properties. They are bound to in WPF, but that part is omitted in this example.
    Public Property Length As New ObjectProperty() With {.Name = "Length", .DependencyProperties = Nothing, .EvaluatingMethod = AddressOf GetLength}
    Public Property Width As New ObjectProperty() With {.Name = "Width", .DependencyProperties = Nothing, .EvaluatingMethod = AddressOf GetWidth}
    Public Property Height As New ObjectProperty() With {.Name = "Height", .DependencyProperties = Nothing, .EvaluatingMethod = AddressOf GetHeight}
    Public Property BoundingBoxDimensions As New ObjectProperty() With {.Name = "BoundingBoxDimensions", .DependencyProperties = New List(Of ObjectProperty) From {Length, Width, Height}, .EvaluatingMethod = AddressOf GetBoundingBoxDimensions}

    'Container for all properties to enable looping.
    Public Property ObjectProperties As New List(Of ObjectProperty) From {Length, Width, Height, BoundingBoxDimensions}

    'Called by the UI to set Requested flags on the object properties that the user requires to be evaluated.
    Public Sub SetObjectPropertyRequests(requestedObjectPropertyNames As List(Of String))
        For Each requestedObjectPropertyName In requestedObjectPropertyNames
            For Each ObjectProperty In ObjectProperties
                If requestedObjectPropertyName = ObjectProperty.Name Then ObjectProperty.Requested = True
            Next
        Next
    End Sub

    'Check Requested flags and evaluate.
    Public Sub CalculateRequestedProperties()
        For Each ObjectProperty In ObjectProperties
            If ObjectProperty.Requested Then Dim tempValue As Object = ObjectProperty.Value
        Next
    End Sub

    'Actual evaluating functions attached to the object properties, making complicated and expensive API calls. This part is simplified in this example.
    Private Function GetLength() As Double
        Return APIConnector.MeasureLength()
    End Function
    Private Function GetWidth() As Double
        Return APIConnector.MeasureWidth()
    End Function
    Private Function GetHeight() As Double
        Return APIConnector.MeasureHeight()
    End Function
    Private Function GetBoundingBoxDimensions() As Double()
        Return {Length.Value, Width.Value, Height.Value}
    End Function
End Class

'Template class for the object properties. Also must be serializable.
Public Class ObjectProperty
    Public ReadOnly Property Value As Object
        Get
            'Check if dependency properties are not evaluated yet; if not, evaluate them first.
            If DependencyProperties IsNot Nothing Then
                For Each DependencyProperty In DependencyProperties
                    If DependencyProperty.State = ObjectPropertyStates.NotEvaluated Then Dim tempValue As Object = DependencyProperty.Value
                Next
            End If

            'Once dependencies are evaluated, evaluate the value of this object property.
            Dim evaluatedValue = EvaluatingMethod()
            State = ObjectPropertyStates.Evaluated
            Return evaluatedValue
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Requested As Boolean = False
    Public Property State As ObjectPropertyStates = ObjectPropertyStates.NotEvaluated
    Public Property DependencyProperties As List(Of ObjectProperty)
    Public Property EvaluatingMethod As EvaluatingMethodDelegate

    Public Delegate Function EvaluatingMethodDelegate() As Object

    Public Enum ObjectPropertyStates
        Evaluated
        NotEvaluated
    End Enum
End Class
```

A lot of actual measurement/evaluating code was simplified in this example to make the code more readable, but this should be a reproducible code.

Now, the issue with this strategy is that I cannot serialize `Study` class, as it contains `ObjectProperty`, which contains `EvaluatingMethodDelegate`, and to my knowledge delegates cannot be serialized.

If I set up the serializer to ignore `EvaluatingMethodDelegate`, then serialization succeeds, but upon deserialization, `EvaluatingMethod` pointers to the respective methods (`GetLength`, `GetWidth`, etc.) on each object are lost.

My question is, how do I solve this issue? Is my whole strategy wrong if I need to use serialization and deserialization? If so, is there a better way of implementing something like this? Or is there some way to simply avoid delegate methods with the current approach? I feel like I'm re-inventing the wheel here.

Comment: You have probably already consulted https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/serialization/ Especially the walkthrough.

Comment: @Mary, yes, I have consulted that document. Unfortunately, it instructs not to serialize an event handler. In my case, I can't avoid serializing these delegate functions, because that's the whole point of the current structure of my application.